# Opened Paradox File Using PypxLib And Need to Insert Data into Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, paradox

I was successful in opening a paradox .db file using PyPxLib and now I am searching for some type of code to insert the rows into a Pandas dataframe.

```
    from pypxlib import Table


    table = Table('d:/Projects/Lakeport/Data/bbrptfav.db')

    try:
          for row in table:
                print(row)
    finally:
          table.close()
```

The resulting data prints out as follows:

```
    Row(Account Code='.5')
    Row(Account Code='01', Account Description='PLAN CHECK')
    Row(Account Code='02', Account Description='BUILDING PERMIT FEE')
```

I would like the resulting data to be inserted into a dataframe

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the [`Table`](https://github.com/mherrmann/pypxlib/blob/master/pypxlib/__init__.py#L13) and the [`Row`](https://github.com/mherrmann/pypxlib/blob/master/pypxlib/__init__.py#L258) classes are roughly an [*OrderedDict*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). So, can you try this ?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(table, columns=table.fields.keys()) #or pd.DataFrame(table)
#or df = pd.DataFrame([dict(row) for row in table], columns=table.fields.keys())
#or df = pd.DataFrame([row.items() for row in table], columns=table.fields.keys())
```

This should give you the following DataFrame :

```
print(df)

  Account Code  Account Description
0           .5                  NaN
1           01           PLAN CHECK
2           02  BUILDING PERMIT FEE
```